# How to insert a line break in Django form after label, and how to assign CSS rules to Text Area so its responsive instead using rows and cols?

Tags: django-forms

To create the field I use:

```
Feedback = forms.CharField(
    label='Survey Feedback', max_length=1200, required=False,   
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'onKeyDown':'return setTimeout(remainingChars, 10);'
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `class` or `style` tag attribute and use CSS to give it the aspects that you want.

```
Feedback = forms.CharField(
    label='Survey Feedback', max_length=1200, required=False,   
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'onKeyDown':'return setTimeout(remainingChars, 10);'
        'class':'responsive-text-area'
    })
);
```